# Drupal 8 Pathauto no Pattern Type

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, pathauto

I've spending hours on an issue i have by configuring Pathauto. 
When I try to add a pattern i'm not able to choose a pattern type. Does anyone know a solution for this or had the same issue before? I'm using drupal 8.8.1 with the latest release of Pathauto.

Thanks in advance for your comments :)

[image]

Comment: Is this from an upgrade? There were issues upgrading pathauto going to 8.8.0. Have you run the update script, either with drush or the UI?

Comment: To add to the above, check the log for errors

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's a fresh d8 installation without any modifications. Thats the reason why I'm quite confused. But it should be also mentioned that I'm a newbie on drupal.

Comment: A full reinstallation of chaos tools, pathauto as token solved the problem